# Parse CSV string in Laravel

Tags: php, string, parsing, csv, laravel

My situation is this: the first ~500kb of a CSV file is encoded as a string and sent as a request to my server, running Laravel. How can I make Laravel parse that string (which is, by itself, not a complete CSV file) to get the column headers and first few rows of data?

I've looked into Goodby/CSV, but it looks as though that can only take a file as input, and not a string. Is there a CSV interpreter plugin that can handle this scenario, or should I expect to have to write a parser of my own?

**Edit**:

Looks like I can do something like this:

```
$Data = str_getcsv($CsvString, "\n"); //parse the rows 
foreach($Data as &$Row) $Row = str_getcsv($Row, ","); //parse the items in rows
```

I was overthinking it, of course.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use the regular php function str_getcsv()?

Comment: Oh perfect. Looks like I can use that first to get the rows, then again to get columns. I'll edit my question.

Comment: I don't understand what this means '(which is, by itself, not a complete CSV file)'

Comment: @JaredEitnier I meant that, because the string sent to the server is not the complete CSV file, the last row of the string could be malformed, which was resulting in some issues trying to parse.

Answer (score 0):

> I've looked into Goodby/CSV, but it looks as though that can only take
>   a file as input, and not a string

If you have [fopen wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled, you can take advantage of the fact that GoodbyCSV uses the `SplFileObject` class internally, and pass the string as a data protocol:

```
$lexer->parse('data://text/plain;base64,' . base64_encode($csv_string), $interpreter);
```

I found this useful when I needed to handle large files as well as simple strings.